# While user tracking is on zoom on user location

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox-android

I am using the version of `mapbox-android-sdk` and `mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer`

```
// Mapbox
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.6.1'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.11.0'
```

One problem I am facing is, once I enable user tracking by setting `cameraMode` to `TRACKING` like below:

```
mapboxMap.locationComponent.cameraMode = CameraMode.TRACKING
```

When I zoom in/out into the map the zoomed location changes from the user tracked position to the pinched/zoomed location of the screen.

Any idea on how to zoom in/out and keep the tracked user location centered and tracking enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you activate your location component, you can add LocationComponentOptions with trackingGesturesManagement enabled

```
val options = LocationComponentOptions.builder(context)
    .trackingGesturesManagement(true)
    .build()
mapboxMap?.locationComponent?.activateLocationComponent(context!!, options)
```

https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/api/map-sdk/6.6.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/location/LocationComponentOptions.html#trackingGesturesManagement--